# Entering data in an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to make a program for a java assignment which reads in names of people.
It has a few options and the one I am having trouble with is the option that lets
the user enter the given name and surname.

What I am having trouble with is that the program must loop so that
when the option is selected, the user will enter details which gets stored
as an element, say array[1]. the next time it loops the details will be stored
as array[2]. I can't figure out how to do this part.

the output will look something like this:

option1: Enter details of person

option2:(some other option)

*user selects option 1*

*details are entered as array[1]*

*program goes back to main menu*

option1: Enter details of person

option2: etc...

*user selects option 1 again*

*this time details go into array[2]*

I have made an array of class type and I have set methods for the details of the people
but I can't figure out how the details will be entered into the next element of the array once the other is full.
Sorry for the long description but it was hard to explain

Comment: (Your question should contain) Less explaining, more code.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Post your code. One rule in SO is to show you have done much job yourself and you are stuck at one place. So post your code and try to have one clear question.

Comment: I said all I have done is declare an array of class type and I have made set methods to enter details. that's all

Comment: Use [Collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) instead of arrays

Comment: @Cirou He says he has an assignment where he has to use arrays and you suggest using collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use a for loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Option 1: Enter details\n
                        Option 2: whatever");
    if(option == 1) {
        //enter details here (probably with scanner)
        details = array[i];
    } else {
        //do something else like break;
    }
}
```

**details = array[i]** would assign whatever they entered to the **i** element of the array. The loop would stop when it gets to the end of the array.

Answer (score -1):

Lists are good way to store the responses if you don't know the number of responses. take in the response and add it to the list with the .add() method. If you must use an array, once you have all the elements in the arraylist, use the Array.asList() to convert it.

Comment: He clearly says he has created the array already: *I have made an array of class type*. So why suggest using collections, especially when the OP isn't likely to have learnt about them yet?